# Oracle :: Error ORA-01858

Tags: oracle

Tengo una tabla en oracle con una columna de tipo texto. Dicha columna almacena fechas en formato dd/mm/yyyy y puede estar o no relleno.

Necesito filtrar en esa tabla y mostrar solo los registros que tengan ese campo relleno con una fecha menor o igual a hoy.

He probado con esto

```
select txt from table where txt is not null and type = 'date'
and TO_DATE(txt, 
'DD/MM/YYYY') <= trunc(sysdate)
```

y con esto

```
select * from (
       select txt from table where txt is not null and type = 'date'
) t where TO_DATE(t.txt, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= trunc(sysdate)
```

y en los dos casos me da un error ORA-01858.

Como lo hago entonces para poder filtrar de esa manera ??? en ese campo puedo almacenar información de distintos tipo: enteros, fechas, cadenas... de ahi que filtre por la columna donde indico el tipo 'date'

Comment: prueba a añadirle al where lo siguiente: `and trim(txt) != ' '` mas que nada porque el `is not null` no te libra de los espacios en blanco, eso si, te irá mas lenta la consulta

Comment: Luego de ver la respuesta y lo que vos decis que tiene el campo, estas 100% seguro que el tipo de campo date solo tiene fechas? porque el error parece ser que algun registro no tiene fecha...

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que comprobar si el valor de ese campo es una fecha valida.

Puedes crearte una funcion que compruebe si es fecha:

```
create function test_date(d varchar2) return integer
is
  v_date date;
begin
  select to_date(d,'DD/MM/YYYY') into v_date from dual;
  return 1;
  exception when others then return 0;
end;
```

Ahora solo tendras que usarla en tu query:

```
select txt from (
   select txt from table where test_date(txt) = 1
) t where TO_DATE(t.txt, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= trunc(sysdate)
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702050/valid-date-checks-in-oracle)

**Edición**

Parece ser que a veces puede ejecutar la parte externa de la query antes de la interna, para esas veces (o para todas) mejor

```
create function test_date(d varchar2) return date
is
  v_date date;
begin
  select to_date(d,'DD/MM/YYYY') into v_date from dual;
  return v_date ;
  exception when others then return NULL;
end;


select txt from (
   select test_date(txt) as txt from table where test_date(txt) != NULL
) t where t.txt <= trunc(sysdate)
```

Comment: Lo he probado como indicas pero nada, sigue dándome el mismo error.

Comment: ¿Donde da el error, en la query o en la función?

Comment: la función va bien, el problema lo da la query. por lo que parece se está ejecutando el where de fuera antes que todo lo de dentro, si no es que no tiene ninguna lógica

Comment: Entonces cambia la funcion para que en vez de devolver un integer devuelva `v_date` o NULL y `select test_date(txt) from table where test_date(txt) != NULL` en la parte de dentro. Te lo edito

Answer (score 0):

Si intentas retirar ese type, ya los casteos los estas haciendo:

```
    select txt from (select txt from table where txt is not null and trim(txt) != '')
     where TO_DATE(txt, 
    'DD/MM/YYYY') <= trunc(sysdate)
```

Espero te sirva!